# Changing an object's (apparent) class at runtime

Tags: design-patterns, language-agnostic

I'm looking for a design pattern to solve the following problem:

An object (let's say representing a document) can change its type dynamically during its lifetime (e.g. when it is saved with a different file extension).

The object contains *many* virtual methods so that depending on the object type it can behave in different ways (e.g. different syntax highlighting).

The application contains many references to the object, which should not become invalid when the object's type changes. So it won't do to destroy the object and create a new one of the new type.

An 'obvious' solution is to use composition, so that the object seen by the application (the outer object) never changes, but it forwards all calls to a contained object that can be destroyed and recreated whenever the type changes.

But this requires a method in the outer object for each virtual method in the contained object to forward the call.

Is there a design pattern that avoids this need for forwarding methods?

(Ideally I'd like a pattern that doesn't require the language to support interfaces.)

---

**Update**

Thanks to comments below, I've identified that the State design pattern implements what I want, *except* that it requires explicitly forwarding every method from the wrapper class to the wrapee class.

So another (perhaps clearer?) way of stating my original question is this: Is there an alternative design pattern that implements the functionality of the State design pattern in (virtually) any object oriented language without needing explicitly to forward every method?

('No' is a perfectly valid answer by the way as long as you can justify it.)

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but if you call IDocument.Save you could return an IDocument, right? This could simply be a decorator which decorates your original object. When calling IDocument.Method1 the decorator forwards the call to your original object.

Comment: Please Note:  If the object contains many virtual methods it may be doing too much and violates the 'Single responsibility principle'. You should have a look at the SOLID principles.

Comment: Anyway, I did not relly get why you need the functionality you described, but I am very curious. Would you be so kind and eyplain the ratio behind your architecture?

Comment: @PaulK Assume for the sake of this question that the application is already written and I'm just extending it to support different document types. So I want the document references to continue to look and be used exactly the same way by the calling code. (But I will, separately, look at your decorator idea - thanks.) Also, assume that 'many' means more forwarding methods than I am happy with but less methods than violates the SRP. (You consider that a contradiction in terms but for the sake of this question please lay that to one side, otherwise we get into a pointless side-debate.)

Comment: @PaulK The rationale behind the architecture is that the requirements are classic polymorphism (i.e. behaviour depends on object type and the caller doesn't have to know anything about it), except that we're not explicitly creating multiple objects of different types; instead we want a single object to exhibit polymorphic behaviour by *apparently* changing its type dynamically.

Comment: There might be a simple answer to this in the context of a particular language... `__class__` for Python, `__proto__` for JavaScript, etc. Otherwise I don't see how you're going to get around some kind of composition/decorator solution.

Comment: @hey That's the point of the question. I don't see how you would get around some kind of composition/decorator solution either, but several of the classic design patterns fall into the category of 'I would never have thought of that' for me :-(

Comment: @IanGoldby You could give each document a "content manager" that does all the stuff your different document types are doing now. I guess it breaks LoD to write something like `document.getContentManager().highlight()`, but at least you won't have to forward all those methods.

Comment: You say, your application contains references to the object, or rather to the interface of the object I hope. If so, just create a DocumentWrapper that implements this interface and stores the real document inside. I then is able to exchange the document while itself staying as it is and just delegates all calles to its inner document. You can then even create different document classes. Is that what you want?

Comment: This looks like a case for the [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), but that also uses composition and manual forwarding of relevant calls.

Comment: "Ideally I'd like a pattern that doesn't require the language to support interfaces" not that agnostic, then. Largely favouring dynamic languages (which mostly do duck typing), by the sound of it.

Comment: @valenterry That's exactly what I want - except that the wrapper still has to have a forwarder method for each method in the inner document class. How to avoid a multitude of forwarder methods was the point of the question.

Comment: @itsbruce By the language-agnostic tag, I mean using only features that are part of (virtually) any object-oriented language. So not just dynamic languages, and no duck-typing. Sorry.

Comment: @IanGoldby In a statically typed language, there is no other choice than using reflection to automatically delegate the methods to the inner object without having to write each of the methods per hand. Your question is therefore not language agnostic, please remove this tag.

Comment: @valenterry It is language agnostic, because I am specifically asking if this can be done in a language-agnostic way. If you don't agree then you've misunderstood my question.

Comment: @valenterry are you sure reflection would be enough? In any statically-typed language I can think of, you'd still need those methods present on the object, or it wouldn't compile (compared with dynamically-typed languages, where there's usually some way to catch attempts at accessing undefined methods/properties).

Comment: @Hey yes, because with reflection you can exchange the classloader and therefore remove and reload a class (with different methods). This is of course very dirty, but possible.

Comment: @valenterry would that really allow you to change the class of an object that was already instantiated, or would it just make it so new instances of that class were different than existing ones? I don't have a lot of experience with Java but I'd be really interested in seeing an example of how a solution to this problem would look using that technique (I realize it's a dirty hack, but it's still interesting).

Answer (score 2):

The solution you describe in your question is usually called the "bridge pattern". Depending on the language in use, there may be a way of implementing it without manually managing all the delegating methods. For example, in Ruby one can simply define the "method_missing" method to perform a dynamic lookup on the target object and dispatch to a method with the same name as the called method. In Java you may be able to use a bytecode generation library to achieve a similar effect, e.g Javassist.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the Bridge pattern. The State pattern is another similar solution. But to do it using only features available in any OO language and without forwarding methods, either a real out-of-the-box idea is needed, or it is simply not possible.